# Weaponize a black hole

Tags: energy, particle-physics, black-holes, hawking-radiation

I saw an interesting concept brought up it's the idea of collapsing something with a mass of 5g into a super tiny black hole. With about a radius of 1x10^-30m. Which in turn would then be destroyed almost instantly by Hawking radiation releasing 450 terajoules of energy and create an explosion roughly 6 times bigger than the Nagasaki bomb.

So my question is is it possible to create a black hole this small? And, do we have the technology to control a black hole enough to weaponize it and not just blow up as soon as we create it?

Comment: This question is... problematic for many reasons. We don't really know how small black holes work at all, since we haven't worked out quantum gravity yet. So it's not really possible to say much for certain.

Comment: We can't create a black hole, period.  Of any size.  And we can't control them either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In nature, creation of black holes is believed to require pressures far beyond anything achievable on Earth. To go from white dwarf to neutron star, one must overcome charge repulsion between protons, to go from neutron star to black hole one must overcome the degeneracy pressure among neutrons that arises from fermi statistics. One faces the same problems in trying to create a black hole, starting with ordinary atomic matter.

When a star collapses, it is gravity which overcomes the repulsion among its constituents. To make a small black hole, one might instead try to collide two (or more?) particles very hard, by artificially accelerating them towards each other, as is done in particle colliders. This might create a micro black hole, but it would immediately evaporate and all you would be left with, is the usual shrapnel following a high-energy collision.

I find it conceivable that you could slowly create a micro black hole, using an atomic bose condensate - let's say of rubidium. It's a collection of rubidium atoms in the same wavefunction because of bose statistics. You could just keep adding rubidium atoms - very carefully, so as not to disturb the condensate - until you had enough mass to create an event horizon... And then it would Hawking-evaporate, i.e. blow up! But I wonder if many-body effects, e.g. among the nuclei, would disrupt the condensate long before that, anyway.

As remarked, the problem of a "micro black hole bomb" is that it blows up immediately upon creation. If it *is* possible to create atomic BECs up to the threshold of black hole creation, then perhaps one could have two BECs below the threshold, and then combine them. It would be analogous to how a nuclear weapon works (combining two subcritical masses).

Another possibility would be to delay detonation by starting with a larger micro black hole, of a mass such that Hawking radiation only trickles out. Let us say that there is a certain rate of Hawking evaporation which is still considered safe, and another rate which corresponds to detonation. A black hole in the safe regime, left to itself, will eventually make its way to the brief, destructive detonation regime; but this can be delayed by feeding it mass-energy.

So one can imagine a collection of black hole bombs - perhaps with nonzero electric charge, to facilitate manipulation by external fields - which are held suspended in electromagnetic cages, and kept in the safe regime through a steady diet of mass-energy; and then when they are to be deployed, their diet is reduced and they are released from their cages.

But all that requires that one has the ability to make moderately large micro black holes; and unless the BEC method works, that may require structures and energies larger than anything that fits on Earth.

Comment: The BEC method wouldn't work, because the Pauli exclusion principle also applies to elementary fermions, of which complex boson like the atom of rubidium consist. While there may not be a degeneracy pressure among the atoms, it will be there among electrons and among nucleons of these atoms. So you wouldn't get anywhere near the event horizon size without a high kinetic energy (collisions).

Comment: @safesphere Can you calculate the BEC mass at which the condensate inescapably destabilizes?